# Jekyll sub-page and assets

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to get Jekyll to reproduce this page and subpage structure:

`_site
 |---assets (global assets)
     |---css
     |---img
     |---js
 |---page-name
     |---index.html
     |---sub-page-name
         |---index.html
         |---assets (sub-page assets)
             |---css
                 |---sub-page.css
             |---img
             |---js`

dev structure looks like this:

`assets
 |---css
 |---img
 |---js
pages
 |---page-name
     |---index.html
     |---sub-page-name
         |---index.html
         |---assets
             |---css
                 |---sub-page.scss
             |---img
             |---js`

but build turns out like this:

`_site
 |---assets
     |---css
     |---img
     |---js
 |---pages
     |---sub-page-name
         |---assets
             |---css
                 |---sub-page.css
             |---img
             |---js
 |---page-name
     |---index.html
     |---sub-page-name
         |---index.html`

In **_config.yml** I have:

`sass:
  sass_dir: assets/css
  style: compressed`

On each sub-page liquid header I have:

`---
layout: default
group: page-name
subgroup: sub-page-name
title: Subpage Title
description: Description
permalink: page-name/sub-page-name/
class: body-class
assets:
  css: assets/css/sub-page-name.css
---`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `permalink` and move `page-name` to the root level, like this:

```
 .
 ├─── assets
 |    ├─── css
 |    ├─── img
 |    └─── js
 └─── page-name
      ├─── index.html
      └─── sub-page-name
           ├─── index.html
           └─── assets
                ├─── css
                |    └─── sub-page.scss
                ├─── img
                └─── js
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the extra `pages` folder but creates a much noisy environment since I will get too much page folders in root mixed with other folders from Jekyll it self. Having permalink or not is the same, I just need to make sure it ends with a trailing slash so that I get the `index.html` file inside the `sub-page-name` folder. While putting `page-name` in root, file `sup-page.scss` doesn't get compiled.